# Drawn a circle around the centroid of a image in opencv-python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to drawn a red circle around the centroid of some objects in a image (the objects in the image are some insects, so the circles would help to a human being to visually detect the insects); I already have the centroids (bellow), but don't know how to do this in python/opencv;

```
array([[  265.,   751.],
   [  383.,   681.],
   [  386.,   889.],
   [  434.,   490.],
   [  446.,   444.],
   [  450.,   451.],
   [  539.,  1365.],
   [  571.,  1365.],
   [  630.,   645.],
   [  721.,  1365.],
   [  767.,    70.],
   [  767.,    82.],
   [  767.,   636.]])
```

Does anyone knows how to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`cv2.circle`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#circle) API as:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

centroids = np.array([[265., 751.],
                      [383., 681.],
                      [386., 889.],
                      [434., 490.],
                      [446., 444.],
                      [450., 451.],
                      [539., 1365.],
                      [571., 1365.],
                      [630., 645.],
                      [721., 1365.],
                      [767., 70.],
                      [767., 82.],
                      [767., 636.]])

canvas = np.ones((1000, 1000, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
CIRCLE_RADIUS = 10
CIRCLE_THICKNESS = 2
COLOR_RED = np.array([0, 0, 255])

for c in centroids:
    o_c = (int(c[0]), int(c[1]))
    cv2.circle(canvas, o_c, CIRCLE_RADIUS, COLOR_RED, CIRCLE_THICKNESS)

cv2.imwrite("./debug.png", canvas)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To draw a circle:

```
cv2.circle(img, center, radius, color, thickness1, lineType, shift)

**Parameters:** 
img (CvArr) – Image where the circle is drawn
center (CvPoint) – Center of the circle
radius (int) – Radius of the circle
color (CvScalar) – Circle color
thickness (int) – Thickness of the circle outline if positive, otherwise this indicates that a filled circle is to be drawn
lineType (int) – Type of the circle boundary, see Line description
shift (int) – Number of fractional bits in the center coordinates and radius value
```

For example:

```
cv2.circle(loaded_cv2_img, (100, 100), 20, (255, 0, 0), 5)
```